# How to wrap Eloquent query with parenthesis when we use a conditional clauses in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a query that should load all the posts with just their english translation.
If the user enter a keyword it return just the english post with a title containing that keyword.

```
if ($searchKeywords||$searchCategory){
    $posts = Post::
        select('post_translations.post_id AS id', 'post_translations.title AS title', 'category_id', 'locale')
           ->join('post_translations', 'posts.id', '=', 'post_translations.post_id')
           ->where(‘post_translations.locale','=','en')
           ->when($searchKeywords, function ($query, $searchKeywords) {
                 return $query->where('post_translations.title', $searchKeywords)->orWhere('post_translations.title', 'like', '%' . $searchKeywords . '%');
            })
           ->when($searchCategory, function ($query, $searchCategory) {
                  return $query->where('category_id', '=', $searchCategory);
            ->paginate(20);
        }
else
    $posts = Post::select('id', 'title', 'category_id')->orderBy('title')->paginate(20);
```

The generated query is this one:

```
SELECT `post_translations`.`post_id` AS `id`, `post_translations`.`title` AS `title`, `category_id` 
FROM `posts` inner join `post_translations` 
ON `posts`.`id` = `post_translations`.`post_id` 
WHERE `post_translations`.`locale` = 'en' 
AND `post_translations`.`title` = 'About' 
OR `post_translations`.`title` like 'About’  
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

That return me all the 3 posts translations of the post About.
This because of the **orWhere**.

How can I change the eloquent query in order to generate a query like this?

```
SELECT `post_translations`.`post_id` AS `id`, `post_translations`.`title` AS `title`, `category_id` 
FROM `posts` inner join `post_translations` 
ON `posts`.`id` = `post_translations`.`post_id` 
WHERE `post_translations`.`locale` = 'en' 
AND (`post_translations`.`title` = ‘About' OR `post_translations`.`title` like 'About’  )
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

The question is not a duplicate of this one because I have one more level of subquery.
[How do you wrap Laravel Eloquent ORM query scopes in parentheses when chaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914650/how-do-you-wrap-laravel-eloquent-orm-query-scopes-in-parentheses-when-chaining)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add both condition inside a where query like this:

```
if ($searchKeywords) {
    $posts = Post::select('post_translations.post_id AS id', 'post_translations.title AS title', 'category_id', 'locale')
       ->join('post_translations', 'posts.id', '=', 'post_translations.post_id')
       ->where(‘post_translations.locale','=','en')
       ->where(function ($query) use ($searchKeywords) {
             $query->where('post_translations.title', $searchKeywords)
                   ->orWhere('post_translations.title', 'like', '%' . $searchKeywords . '%');
        })
        ->paginate(20);
}
```

Comment: This should work, anyway my query is a bit more complicated, i've updated it.
I have two search fields, **$searchKeywords** and **$searchCategory**. So I need to keep the **when** condition.

Comment: You can add this where condition in same way inside when.

Comment: I don't understand.  If I do like this the problem is the same.
$query->where(‘post_translations.locale','=','en')->where('post_translations.title', $searchKeywords)->orWhere('post_translations.title', 'like', '%' . $searchKeywords . '%');

Comment: Because it generate:
WHERE `post_translations`.`locale` = 'en' AND `post_translations`.`title` = 'About' 
OR `post_translations`.`title` like 'About'  limit 20 offset 0

Comment: Use it in this way $query->where(‘post_translations.locale','=','en')->where(function ($query) use ($searchKeywords) {
             $query->where('post_translations.title', $searchKeywords)
                   ->orWhere('post_translations.title', 'like', '%' . $searchKeywords . '%');
        })

Answer (score 1):

**I have solved with this code:**

```
if ($searchKeywords||$searchCategory){
    $posts = Post::
            select('post_translations.post_id AS id', 'post_translations.title AS title', 'category_id', 'locale')
            ->join('post_translations', 'posts.id', '=', 'post_translations.post_id')
            ->when($searchKeywords, function ($query, $searchKeywords) {
                return $query->where('post_translations.locale','=','en')
                             ->where(function ($query) use ($searchKeywords) { 
                                  $query->where('post_translations.title', $searchKeywords)->orWhere('post_translations.title', 'like', '%' . $searchKeywords . '%');
                              });

            })
            ->when($searchCategory, function ($query, $searchCategory) {
               return $query->where('post_translations.locale','=','en')
                            ->where(function ($query) use ($searchCategory) { 
                                $query->where('category_id', '=', $searchCategory);
                             });
            })
            ->paginate(20);
}
else
    $posts = Post::select('id', 'title', 'category_id')->orderBy('title')->paginate(20);
```