# I have problem with my query using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am building a simple private chat app with laravel.

I have a messages table with a column : id/sender_id/receiver_id and body

I am trying to show chat history related to user when i select to any user but unfortunately my query is not working properly  all users seeing all message please help me how can i resolved that thank u.

[image]

**Controller**

```
            Message::where('sender_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->orWhere('receiver_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('sender_id', $userId)
             ->orWhere('receiver_id', $userId)
             ->get();
```

Comment: that `orWhere` isnt scoped correctly. You will want to use `->where(function($q) { $q->where()->orWhere(); });`

Comment: please can you update my query ? thank u.

Comment: the StackOverflow coding service has already provided 2 answers below. Please consider becoming a sponsor; also like comment and subscribe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you wrap Laravel Eloquent ORM query scopes in parentheses when chaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914650/how-do-you-wrap-laravel-eloquent-orm-query-scopes-in-parentheses-when-chaining)

Answer (score 0):

make subquery where like this:

```
 Message::where(function($q){
             $q->where('sender_id', Auth::user()->id)
               ->orWhere('receiver_id', Auth::user()->id);
          })->where(function($q){
             $q->where('sender_id', $userId)
               ->orWhere('receiver_id', $userId)
          })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `->where(function($q){})` case orWhere breakdown all other conditions
try this code

```
Message::where(function ($q) {
            $q->where('sender_id', Auth::user()->id)
              ->orWhere('receiver_id', Auth::user()->id);
        })->where(function ($q) {
            $q->where('sender_id', $userId)
              ->orWhere('receiver_id', $userId);
        })->get();
```

Comment: i have used this query but chat messages is not showing .

Comment: is there any error ? provide me with more details

Comment: i am not getting error just messages is not showing on chat  please check https://ibb.co/KbvHBRZ

Comment: try to dd($userId,Auth::user()->id) is there data ?

Comment: after this  dd(Auth::user()->id); getting auth user id  177

Comment: I Updated my answer could you try again

Comment: i have updated your code but why all chat message is showing to all users please check https://ibb.co/4WXv2PZ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245001/discussion-between-zubair-syslab-and-wael-khalifa).